# How to limit information requested by my facebook app

Tags: facebook, privacy

I'm using facebook connect to allow the visitors login to a website using their facebook account.

The only information needed is that the user id and name.

However the facebook connect dialog states that my app will access all the users friends, photos...

How can I configure my facebook application to not request those data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer, you can't. The dialog states that you have the ability to access the user's information. Whether you access it or not is up to you, but the ability to is always there. There is a base level of access granted to all apps. You can prompt for extended permissions, but you can't customize the base level.

This may change going forward with OpenGraph. There are still features Facebook is adding, and some existing, undocumented features.